# div width in view with value of variable

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I want to change the value of the width in a `div` according to a variable. I am doing something like this in the view:

```
<% @answers.each do |answer| %>
  <%= @poll.responses.find_all_by_answer_id(answer.id).count %></br>
  <% divwidth = @poll.responses.find_all_by_answer_id(answer.id).count.to_int * 10 %> 
  <div class="poll" width=<%= divwidth.to_s + 'px' %>></div> 
<% end %>
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add width with style property,

```
<div class="poll" style="<%="width:#{divwidth}px;"%>"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for this so belated acception i didn't know that this icone is clickable

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the width of a `<div>` using the `style` attribute. Here is a simple example:

```
<div style="width:400px;">
```